# handle out parameters

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
public static long callproc()
{
    DbCommand command = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.proc");
    db.AddOutParameter(command, "@proc_id", DbType.Int64, 8);
    db.ExecuteNonQuery(command);
    return long.Parse(db.GetParameterValue(command, "@proc_id").ToString());
}
```

Is this the best way to use out parameter?

Answer (score 2):

The function `GetParameterValue()` is not part of the .NET framework, so I'm not sure what it does.

In any case, it looks like you're converting a `SqlInt64` to `string` and then to a `long`.  This will work, but it's the long way around.  There is an implicit conversion between `SqlInt64` and `long`.  Try:

```
return (long) command.Parameters["@proc_id"].Value;
```

This avoids the need for an intermediate `string`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. What about the size of the variable in "db.AddOutParameter(command, "@proc_id", DbType.Int64, 8)"? How can I be sure it will be 8?

Comment: @Naor: An `Int64` takes 64 bits, so it'll probably always take up 8 bytes.  The `size` parameter is optional, in my experience it's only required for strings.

Comment: @Naor: The `AddOutputParameter` isn't part of ADO.NET. Using the standard ADO.NET functions, you could `command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { DbType = DbType.Int64, ParameterName = "@proc_id" });`